# How to Resize Image and save in folder?

Tags: c#, image-resizing

I tried this:

```
string str = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtImage.Text);
string pth = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Subject";
string fullpath = pth + "\\" + str;

Image NewImage = clsImage.ResizeImage(fullpath, 130, 140, true);
NewImage.Save(fullpath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

---

```
public static Image ResizeImage(string file, int width, int height, bool onlyResizeIfWider)
{
    if (File.Exists(file) == false)
        return null;
    try
    {
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(file))
        {
            // Prevent using images internal thumbnail
            image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            if (onlyResizeIfWider == true)
            {
                if (image.Width <= width)
                {
                    width = image.Width;
                }
            }
            int newHeight = image.Height * width / image.Width;
            if (newHeight > height)
            {
                // Resize with height instead
                width = image.Width * height / image.Height;
                newHeight = height;
            }
            Image NewImage = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            return NewImage;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Running the above code, I get an image 4-5 KB in size with very poor image quality.
The original image file is no more than 1.5 MB large. How can I improve the image quality of the results?

Comment: Your use of `RotateFlip` is strange. I see the comment, but this just looks like cargo cult programming to me.

Comment: Which `Image` class are you using? In what namespace? When saving, use an overload that takes `EncoderParameters` with a quality setting of `High`.

Comment: can you give me the link for that @Oded

Comment: The RotateFlip actually prevents GetThumbnailImage from using the embedded thumbnail, but it still produces horrible quality results.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use [Image Resizer](http://imageresizing.net/), its free and resizing an image is very easy using it.

```
var settings = new ResizeSettings {
MaxWidth = thumbnailSize,
MaxHeight = thumbnailSize,
Format = "jpg"
};
settings.Add("quality", quality.ToString());
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inStream, outStream, settings);
resized = outStream.ToArray();
```

You can also install it using Nuget package manager.

```
PM> Install-Package ImageResizer
```

Comment: what i pass in inStream and outStream?

Comment: You should pass image to resize in 'inStream' and resized image in 'outStream'. You can pass new MemoryStream() as outStream.

Comment: You can also just pass it filenames for either parameter.